# how to install stock rom from recovery?

Tags: custom-roms, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-note, stock-android

first I saw my phone is off and then I tried to turn it on but it hanged on Galaxy note welcome page, so I do Factory reset ,wipe cache and Dalvik cache and System, but while I want to reboot from Team Win Recovery Project I saw `No OS installed, Are you sure you wish reboot?`

after rebooting it hanged again in same page
I think I need to install stock rom but I don't find any stock that i can install from recovery, all of them need Odin

downloading mode doesn't work and I had installed 4.1.2 and vAlliance custom rom v3

Answer (score 0):

It got stuck in boot loop due to reset where the bootloader is not getting the correct file to load. The only way to fix it is to use Odin to get a stock ROM. Any deodexed ROM (stock ROM) can also be used from recovery mode, if it is able to start in recovery mode.